# wso2 iot devicemgt redirects to localhost acs

Tags: wso2, iot

trying to log in into the WSO2 IoT server 3.0.0 to /devicemgt I am redirected to the logon page and after authentication the server redirets me to https://localhost:9443/devicemgt/uuf/sso/acs

I've update the io.keymanager.host in the wso2server.bat already

where do I set the ACS host (for the devicemgt, publisher and store)?

Answer (score 1):

you may update your /etc/hosts file :

- Comment "127.0.0.1 localhost"
- Add "ip_iot_server localhost"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSO2IoT-3.0.0, you will find the sso-idp-config.xml file in /repository/conf/identity/. You will find the SSO configurations as follows. Please change the 'AssertionConsumerServiceURL' and 'DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL' respectively.

```
<SSOIdentityProviderConfig>
<TenantRegistrationPage>https://stratos-local.wso2.com/carbon/tenant-register/select_domain.jsp</TenantRegistrationPage>
<ServiceProviders>
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>devicemgt</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
            <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/devicemgt/uuf/sso/acs</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/devicemgt/uuf/sso/acs</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <SignAssertion>true</SignAssertion>
        <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
        <EnableAttributeProfile>false</EnableAttributeProfile>
        <IncludeAttributeByDefault>false</IncludeAttributeByDefault>
        <Claims>
            <Claim>http://wso2.org/claims/role</Claim>
            <Claim>http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress</Claim>
        </Claims>
        <EnableAudienceRestriction>true</EnableAudienceRestriction>
        <EnableRecipients>true</EnableRecipients>
        <AudiencesList>
            <Audience>https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token</Audience>
        </AudiencesList>
        <RecipientList>
            <Recipient>https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token</Recipient>
        </RecipientList>
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>store</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
            <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/store/acs</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/store/acs</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
        <CustomLoginPage>/store/login.jag</CustomLoginPage>
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>social</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
            <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/social/acs</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/social/acs</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
        <CustomLoginPage>/social/login</CustomLoginPage>
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>publisher</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
            <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/publisher/acs</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/publisher/acs</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
        <CustomLoginPage>/publisher/controllers/login.jag</CustomLoginPage>
        <EnableAudienceRestriction>true</EnableAudienceRestriction>
        <AudiencesList>
            <Audience>carbonServer</Audience>
        </AudiencesList>
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>API_STORE</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
            <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/api-store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/api-store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
        <EnableAudienceRestriction>true</EnableAudienceRestriction>
        <AudiencesList>
            <Audience>carbonServer</Audience>
        </AudiencesList>
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>portal</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
            <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/portal/acs</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9443/portal/acs</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
        <EnableAudienceRestriction>true</EnableAudienceRestriction>
        <EnableRecipients>true</EnableRecipients>
        <AudiencesList>
            <Audience>https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token</Audience>
        </AudiencesList>
        <RecipientList>
            <Recipient>https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token</Recipient>
        </RecipientList>
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider>
        <Issuer>analyticsportal</Issuer>
        <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
            <AssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9445/portal/acs</AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
        <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>https://localhost:9445/portal/acs</DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
        <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
        <EnableAudienceRestriction>true</EnableAudienceRestriction>
        <EnableRecipients>true</EnableRecipients>
        <AudiencesList>
            <Audience>https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token</Audience>
        </AudiencesList>
        <RecipientList>
            <Recipient>https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token</Recipient>
        </RecipientList>
    </ServiceProvider>
</ServiceProviders>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to modify any XML to change the IP. there is script called

```
./change-ip.sh
```

it will do that for you.
also make sure your machine IP is in your

```
 /etc/hosts
```

edit:
This will work only under Linux like OS, did't found similar script for Windows OS